# LastWriteTime is not sorting as a DateTime

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to loop through a directory, and delete all but the 10 newest folders. After jumping through a bunch of questions, I get to this

```
$folder = "C:\Projects\BuildDeleteTest"
$keep = 10
$folders = Get-ChildItem $folder

#echo $folders
#echo $folders.Count
echo $folders | Sort-Object -Property $_.LastWriteTime.DateTime | Select-Object -First (20)
```

And I can delete all the items and then the folders.  However, the LastWriteDateTime is not actually sorting as a DateTime, since my folder list is

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name 
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       12/21/2018  10:01 AM                01 - Copy (12)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:01 AM                01 - Copy (13)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:02 AM                01 - Copy (14)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:02 AM                01 - Copy (15)
d-----       12/21/2018   9:35 AM                01 - Copy (16)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:01 AM                01 - Copy (17)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:06 AM                01 - Copy (17) - Copy
d-----       12/21/2018  10:03 AM                01 - Copy (2)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:04 AM                01 - Copy (2) - Copy
d-----       12/21/2018  10:03 AM                01 - Copy (3)
d-----       12/21/2018  10:04 AM                01 - Copy (3) - Copy
```

Clearly, `01 - Copy (16)` is the oldest file, and should return at the top of the list, but it does not. Sort Ascending *always* returns `Copy (12)` as the first and Descending *always* returns `01 - Copy (3) - Copy`. Further, all of the folders after `Copy (16)` are clearly out of order.

How do I get a properly sorted array of folders, based on LastWriteTime?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I originally had just `$_.LastWriteTime` and got the same results.  Adding `.DateTime` was one of many, many attempts to get it to actually sort as a `DateTime`

Comment: Actually `Sort-Object` uses the property name _itself_. All you need is `Get-ChildItem $folders | Sort-Object LastWriteTime` (not `$_.LastWriteTime`).

Comment: $folders | Sort-Object CreationTime | select-Object -First 1

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That worked.  I changed `$folders` to the sorted list and loop through that.  If you add as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be specifying only the name of the property as the argument to `Sort-Object`. That is, write `Sort-Object LastWriteTime` rather than `Sort-Object $_.LastWriteTime`.